# Copy of object or const pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, game-engine

I've made a 2d game engine, but I'm questioning if one way I did things is the best way to do things structurally.  For example, a member of Sprite can have multiple Graphic members.  Right now I'm keeping those members in a `vector<const Graphic*>` (not `std::vector`, but I will use that for simplicity in the example):

```
class Sprite {
private:
    std::vector<const Graphic*> _graphicList;
public:
    Sprite();
    ~Sprite();
    void addGraphic(const Graphic* toAdd); //adds a const Graphic* to _graphicList
    void draw() const; //draws all items in _graphicList
};
```

The above example works fine.  The problem is, I need to keep my Graphic object in scope for this to work.  This would produce an error:

```
void foo (bool redCircle) {
    Sprite sprCircle;
    if(redCircle) {
        Graphic gfxRedCircle("redCircle.bmp");
        sprCircle.addGraphic(&gfxRedCircle);
    }
    else {
        Graphic gfxBlueCircle("blueCircle.bmp");
        sprCircle.addGraphic(&gfxBlueCircle);
    }
    sprCircle.draw(); //would possibly not work, since the Graphic is out of scope
}
```

I could just create copies:

```
class Sprite {
private:
    std::vector<Graphic> _graphicList;
public:
    Sprite();
    ~Sprite();
    void addGraphic(Graphic& toAdd); //adds a Graphic to _graphicList
    void draw() const; //draws all items in _graphicList
};
```

However this would waste precious memory if I keep the Graphic in scope.

So I guess my question boils down to this:
In a game engine, which is more important: robustness or efficient memory usage?

Comment: If you're worried about memory usage, then why are you creating local copies in the first place? Why not load the images once and globally, and then pass pointers to those textures around?

Comment: @remyable, this is a much simplified example.  The actual image is only loaded once, however you can have many Graphic objects that contain a pointer to the actual image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is out of scope, any attempt to use it by pointer or reference has undefined behavior by the C++ language standard (meaning, it might corrupt some other object, or it might crash a program, or kill your cat the most gruesome way). Therefore it is not a question *if* the object should be in scope - it *must* be!

Again, robustness is a quality you don't want to trade for anything. If your program crashes, the user will not care how little memory it is using. To optimize your program in memory usage, you should carefully consider many factors - *where* does your program use most memory, how you can lower this usage, and what tricks you could pull in order to make your memory footprint lower (for example by caching and heavily re-using existing objects). Each of those factors is heavily dependent on *your specific program* so discussing it in general is hardly useful for your specific purpose.

Comment: I know it must be in scope.  The `//would possibly not work, since the Graphic is out of scope` comment was specifically pointing out that the behavior was undefined.  It might seem to work,  but it's not guaranteed and not good practice.  Thank you for your opinions.  This is what I was thinking, but I wanted to consult someone else before making such a big change to my code base.

Answer (score 0):

Correctness should be the first consideration. Using out of scope object is definitely wrong and your program can abort/hangup (undefined behaviour).

There are some ways, depends on what you need:

- Copy the object

> `void addGraphic(const Graphic &toAdd);`

This may mean you need to implement deep copy / copy constructor operation if the Graphic object contains pointers and you want a perfect clone of it (not just referring to the same memory). If you don't do deeep copy, the original object maybe freed and you still referring the freed memory.

- Create the object yourself

> ```
> void addGraphic(const string &bmpName);
> ```

Just create Graphic object inside addGraphic yourself then put in in the vector, this way you own the object, it won't be out of scope.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not using the object out of scope.  But it's a possibility that could arise if anyone else changes the code base or even if I go back to it a year from now to fix bugs and forget.  All object that need a deep copy, already have a copy constructor.  Not passing a path the the file to the sprite was a conscious design choice.